# How to reference a .java class file located in /libs directory, in the AndroidManifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, game-maker

When I have a class (a broadcast receiver in this case) inside my main package, and I want to reference it in the `AndroidManifest.xml` I do it like this:

```
    <!-- Used for install referrer tracking -->
    <receiver
        android:name=".MainActivity$InstallReferrerReceiver"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Also here is the said receiver:

```
    public class InstallReferrerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String referrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");
        Log.e("INSTALL_REFERRER_P", referrer);
        //Use the referrer
    }
}
```

But what if I need to reference the .java file, if its located directly in the `/java` directory of my project? How can I do that?

I need this, because it is for a GameMaker extension, where all .java files are put in the `/Java` folder.

EDIT: Actually it was in a Java folder.

Comment: you can use bye package name and .calss name. like : "com.example.library.activity"

Comment: Have you seen `<uses-library>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

> where all .java files are put in the /libs folder.

You cannot put your `.java` files in the `libs` folder because it is for `.jar` files.